# Relayout UICollectionView when tap the header

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to do collapsible `UICollectionView`. The collection view should show smaller items in section when user tap on the header.

[image]

Please suggest me where should I start. Should I go for custom `UICollectionViewLayout` or `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

(I think the second one is more interesting)? If there are other ways of doing this stuff, please give me some resources so I do further research.

Answer (score 0):

You could of course use a custom Layout. I'd first play around with the UICollectionViewFlowLayout before moving on.

There are things you could do to achieve that effect with just the flow layout. This is purely theoretical. I haven't tried it.

I might attempt to do this using `FlowLayout` subject to the data object being the same.

1. Subclass `UICollectionReusableView` Add a `TapGesture` to it add it as the Section Header.
2. Preset a CGSize for ItemSizes
3. On `Tap`- change ItemSize of for Objects in that section.
4. Reload Section.